# Matching a data-set from a certain table in R

Tags: r, join, matching

I would like this process...

Original one;

```
A     B
LN1   1
LN2   2
LN3   3
```

Table

```
A   
LN1   
LN4
```

What I want

```
A     B
LN1   1
LN2   2
LN3   3
LN4   1
```

I would like to paste the original one to refer the table like LN1 with the attributes (LN1-1; LN4-1 caused the table)... How do I make the code?

Comment: Try join functions from the `dplyr` package!

Answer (score 1):

```
df1 = read.table(text = "
A     B
LN1   1
LN2   2
LN3   3
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

df2 = data.frame(A = c("LN1","LN4"), stringsAsFactors = F)

library(dplyr)

left_join(df2, df1, by="A") %>%         # join datasets
  mutate(B = unique(B[!is.na(B)])) %>%  # replace NAs in column B with the unique non-NA value
  bind_rows(df1) %>%                    # bind original dataset
  distinct()                            # keep distinct rows

#     A B
# 1 LN1 1
# 2 LN4 1
# 3 LN2 2
# 4 LN3 3
```